# MongoDB Compass: Current topology does not support sessions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

All of a sudden I am getting an error - 'Current topology does not support sessions' on MongoDB Compass. I have never seen this before on MongoDB Compass!!!

Below are the details on version/server

MongoDB Compass Version: 1.29.5 (1.29.5)

MongoDB Version: MongoDB 3.0.6 Community

Cluster : Standalone
Host : AWS EC2

[image].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe this is an issue due to the mongoDB version is not compatible with the latest version of MongoDB Compass.

Solution: Downgraded MongoDB Compass version to 1.28.4 (1.28.4).

Link - https://github.com/mongodb-js/compass/releases?q=1.28.4&expanded=true ... look for required installer under Assets.

[image]

Comment: i love you man...

Comment: https://www.filehorse.com/download-mongodb-compass/old-versions
you can download the version from this link(30th August 2021 release)

Comment: Is there a way, instead of trying to match versions, to just toggle an option in Compass so that it *doesn't use sessions* and just behaves like it did in the old version? Seems ridiculous that a db query tool has to exactly match the db version, especially when you might need to support multiple installs of different versions.

Comment: not that I am aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried hard and didn't end well :(

So I switched to another tool.

Try https://nosqlbooster.com/

Comment: Same here.. I have started using new tool called Robo3T

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, and it turned out I had several versions of Mongo installed at the same time.

Are you by any change seeing this, running mongo localhost on a Mac?
If so, try this:
First off, run `brew services list`. Do you have more than one version running? I had 3.6, 4.2 and 5.1 installed at once. Sadly the older one was in use (and Mongo <4 does not support Sessions. Hence the error you see!)

[image: brew-services-list]

Removing old versions, is quite easy. First we stop the service, then we remove all the versions we don't like, and at the end we restart the service. I wanted to remove version 3.6 and 4.2:

```
brew services stop mongodb-community

brew uninstall mongodb-community@3.6
brew uninstall mongodb-community@4.2

brew services restart mongodb-community
```

(Perhaps you want to remove all versions of mongodb-community, and re-install the newest version? No problems, just remember to `brew upgrade` first, then `brew install mongodb-community`.)

There you go! But .. oh .. perhaps I should have told you to **BACK UP YOUR DATA?**

My old 3.6-database was using another engine than the brand new one. Therefor I was not able to actually start mongo. Luckily for me, I didn't have any vital data, so I just wiped it all.

How to completely wipe* your mongo:

```
brew services stop mongodb-community

mv /usr/local/var/mongodb /usr/local/var/mongodb.bak
mkdir /usr/local/var/mongodb

brew services restart mongodb-community
```

*) As you see, old data is moved to the catalog `mongodb.bak`.